# Mac Terminal Printing Contents of Python Files, AND Executing

Tags: python, macos, terminal

I have a weird problem here. I've got a macbook that I'm trying to run a python script on. The script contains only the following lines:

```
#test
print "hello, world"
#test
#test
```

Anytime I execute *python myfile.py* I get the following output:

```
hello, world

#test
print "hello, world"
#test
#test
```

It's the strangest thing, it seems to be printing the hello world , but also printing the entire contents of the file including the hello world statement. I can run this on my linux box just fine, but this mac seems to have other plans. Python is installed, and when I enter the python shell I can type print commands that run just fine without this funny business.

Comment: Add the output of `which python` and `python --version`.

Comment: /Applications/anaconda/bin/python

Comment: Python 2.7.10 :: Anaconda 2.3.0 (x86_64)

Comment: Apparently this is an issue with Anaconda's Python build. No idea why. `/usr/bin/python` probably wouldn't have the problem

Comment: Perfect, thanks! If you post this as the answer I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently this is an issue with Anaconda's Python build. I have no idea why Anaconda's Python would also output the source, but you could use the Apple-provided python.

```
/usr/bin/python myfile.py
```

Or you can adjust your path so this directory appears first.

```
export PATH="/usr/bin:$PATH"
```

On a side note, it appears Anaconda2 2.5.0 is the latest in the Python 2 series, you could try updating it and see if the issue persists. I tried installing this version in a VM, and the issue does not appear to be present.